# How to push on div box under the other? In Bootrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

it seems easy, but I just want to push the 1b div under the 1a div. 
As you may see, my code is based on bootstrap. Is there something like a helper class to sollte this problem?

Thank you!

```
<div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">Div 1a</div>
<div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lightcyan;">Div 1b</div>
<div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavender; height:100px;">Div 2</div>
<div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lightgray;"> Div 3</div>
```

Comment: Show some image what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a container for that and put 1a and 1b in that container, something like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 the-container">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">Div 1a</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:lightcyan;">Div 1b</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavender; height:100px;">Div 2</div>
<div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lightgray;"> Div 3</div>
```

Then with the col-sm-12 for both, you'll make them to be 100% width.

P.S. Also, you might have some padding, you can clear that by adding a row class to the parent.